# Are JAR files in WebContent/WEB-INF/lib available to Java design elements in Domino Designer?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, lotus, xpages-ssjs

When using Domino Designer 8.5.3, I have a bunch of custom classes added using the Java design element. I want to use a 3rd party JAR in my custom classes in the same way you would when using external JARs in xPages SSJS, via Package Explorer:

WebContent-->WEB-INF-->lib

However my custom classes aren't picking the JAR up.

Is this a known limitation or have I got my configuration screwed up somewhere?

Comment: Do you mean Agents? If so, no it can't use them.

Comment: They aren't being picked up in Designer or at runtime?  You can do this.  I have done it from managed beans.

Comment: Russell, they aren't being picked up in Designer. So I'm just getting "...cannot be resolved" errors when saving.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are after you do:

*Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add JARS...*

**update:**

Frantisek Kossuth tells us about a nice shortcut in his comment:

> in Package Explorer view (Java perspective, or add this view to
>   XPages/Domino Designer perspective), simply right click JAR file and
>   use "Build Path/Add to Build Path" menu

Comment: Hi Paul. Yes that solves the issue of the Java class picking up the JAR in Designer. However when the code then runs via the xpage through the browser, a NoClassDefFoundError is thrown.

Comment: I often have to clean the project or rebuild when that kind of errors appear.

Comment: Yes that was my thinking too so have done a clean and a rebuild but still no luck.

Comment: Some suggestions here: http://lotusandjava.blogspot.fi/2012/10/xpage-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html

Comment: Thanks Panu. I created a fresh NSF and tried what you suggested which then worked fine. Led me to think there must be an issue with the NSF I was working on. Removed my replica and pulled a fresh one. Tried what you suggested and it worked. Frustrating! Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you use these jar files often it would best to add them to the jvm/ext directory on your server directly. Because adding Jar files to a notes designer increases build times enormously for some reason.

Comment: If you are in Package Explorer view (Java perspective, or add this view to XPages/Domino Designer perspective), simply right click JAR file and use "Build Path/Add to Build Path" menu.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem ([Accessing methods from imported jars in managed beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142840/accessing-methods-from-imported-jars-in-managed-beans)). It seems you need to import them in your machine/server's file system.