# Accessing Java method in xpage repeat control

Tags: xpages

I've created a Java Script Library which has a java class that contains some jdbc code.

It has a method to get values from a database (mysql).

Now i need to access it in the **repeat control** like `<xp:repeat value = ?? >`

But i don't find a way to access it there.

If it is a javascript library, the method is accessed as `<xp:repeat value="#{javascript:getSQLData()}"`

How to achieve it? And is it the right approach to use java in script libraries when we also have a separate application named Java inside the Code Section (below script library in the application view).

My java code is:

```
package com.db;
```

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Db {

```
Connection con;
Statement st;
ResultSet rs;

public Db(){

    this.connect("localhost", "3306", "vijay", "root", "");
    try {
        this.query("select * from prodet;");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        System.out.println("///////////////query///////////////////////////////////////////");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void connect(String server, String port, String db, String user, String pwd){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con=DriverManager
        .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/vijay","root", "");
    //con=DriverManager.getConnection("\"jdbc:mysql://"+server+":"+port+"/"+db+"\""+","+"\""+user+"\""+","+"\""+pwd+"\"");
        st=con.createStatement();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

List arr = new ArrayList();


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void query(String q) throws SQLException{
    rs=st.executeQuery(q);      
            while(rs.next()){
                arr.add(rs.getString(2));
                arr.add(rs.getInt(3));

            }
}

public String getData(){

     String arra = arr.toString();
    return arra;
}

public String doAllDb(){

    return this.getData();
}

public static void main(String a[]){
    Db d = new Db();

        System.out.println(d.getData());
}
```

}

And the ssjs to access the method is:

```
importPackage(com.db);
```

var v = new com.db.Db();
 v.doAllDb();

This ssjs is written under Bind data using ssjs.

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:importPackage(com.db);
```

var v = new com.db.Db();
 v.doAllDb();}]]>
    .

When the xpage is previewed, it is blank. Doesn't show any value. But i tested the java code. It is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I use managed beans all the time to do exactly that :-)

```
<xp:repeat rows="10" var="row" value="#{User.rowClubs}">
```

"User" is my managed bean. It has to be a Java bean that implements the serializable interface, has a constructor without arguments and has public getters/setters for access to properties. In my example the User bean implements the method getRowClubs() that returns a list of objects representing rows of clubs (from the application I worked on this morning).

Please let me know if you need any more help with managed beans? From your question I guessed you needed help on how to reference methods in your bean.

**Edit**

I just saw the rest of your bean (in the scrollable view). Using your bean you would use something like:

```
<xp:repeat id="repeat1" rows="30" value="Db.data" var="row">
```

assuming that you have defined your bean in faces-config.xml, e.g.:

```
  <managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>Db</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.db.Db</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
  </managed-bean>
```

I would also recommend that you remove your "main" method from the bean. If you need to test it from an ordinary Java program then create a test class with a "main" that instantiates and runs your bean.

/John

Comment: Pls see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16932516/ssjs-to-call-a-method-in-java-class-in-java-library. Actually John, i'm trying a similar thing.

Comment: The java code executed in ECLIPSE worked fine pal. Here in Designer, i just have the methods and no Main method is used. But i don't get any value.

Comment: Ok. I suggest you try to add some dummy values to your getter to isolate the problem to find out if it is a syntax/reference issue - or a config/context issue with the db configuration?