# How to resolve NoClassDefFoundError Java agent

Tags: java, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

Suddenly when trying to add an external library (jar) from disk to my database I get NoClassDefFoundError when running the agent.
This has worked before without any hustle.

```
[0A04:001B-13BC] 2014-01-21 11:24:57   AMgr: Start executing agent 'areadregis' in 'kunder\lf\emir.nsf'
[0A04:001E-0F38] 2014-01-21 11:24:57   Agent Manager: Agent  error: Exception in thread "AgentThread: readRegis"
[0A04:001F-0F38] 2014-01-21 11:24:57   Agent Manager: Agent  error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.i
o.FileUtils
```

In reference to this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464827/are-jar-files-in-webcontent-web-inf-lib-available-to-java-design-elements-in-dom
I have tried all tips but still failing.

My code gets an error when referencing the library and suggest me to add it to Build Path. The thing is that it is already in my build path.

If I add the jar file to WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/ and the right-click and add to Build Path it moves up to Referenced Libraries.
The Java agent compiles without errors or warnings but when running it stops with an other error:

```
[19D8:01CB-17D8] 2014-01-21 11:13:25   Agent Manager: Agent  error: Exception in thread "Launcher: readRegis"
[19D8:01CC-17D8] 2014-01-21 11:13:25   Agent Manager: Agent  error: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
The import org.apache.commons.io cannot be resolved     FileUtils cannot be resolved
```

running Domino 9.0.1 Win/64

Please advice

Comment: can you tell java version

Comment: 1.6.0 is serverside java version

Comment: Already deployed you server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you can't use a jar file that's in WebContent\WEB-INF in a Java agent. From that location it's only accessible to Java classes for XPages etc.

If you add it directly to the agent or a Script Library, it should work.

Comment: I was wrong and feel kind of stupid. Let me revise this and return!

Comment: Please consider this topic as invalid, I was totally barking at the wrong tree here. Paul corrected me!

My bad, sorry

Comment: To add to that answer you can also put your jars in the lib/ext folder so agents can access it.

Comment: AFAIK (http://goo.gl/ZJkQlc), putting JARs in Java agent and Java script library causes memory leaks a can lead to server crash. Preferred solution (for agents) is to put JARs in jvm/lib/ext directory.

Answer (score 1):

I've had same issue. In my case it happened because I've different version of Java Compiler in agent and in libraries.